# How to update tables in fields after amending existing information

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I currently need to add to tables that update each time the user clicks the "Save" button on a program that updates any of their information.
When any of the fields are amended, in order that we have a log of the changes, I need to create a record on a "slinfo" table including things like:

```
Customer name (slinfo.name)
Customer account (slinfo.acode)
The date      (slinfo.date)
And slinfo.seq, which is the sequence number for each change.
```

How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

you can handle this with **Database Triggers**
https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920170039.html

you have also access to the old field value and the new field value in the trigger statement

simple write procedure:

```
TRIGGER PROCEDURE FOR WRITE OF Customer

CREATE slinfo.
ASSIGN
  slinfo.name  = Customer.NAME
  slinfo.acode = Customer.account 
  slinfo.date  = TODAY
  slinfo.seq   = NEXT-VALUE(seqSlinfo)
.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* presumably you already have a save trigger to save the amended values
 * this code should go in that trigger, probably at the end
 */

/* I, obviously, have no way to know where the actual values for
 * these variables are supposed to come from. if the logic for
 * that is simple enough you might even be able to eliminate the variables
 */

define variable nameVariable as character no-undo.
define variable acodeVariable as character no-undo. /* I'm guessing that this is a character field */
define variable seqVariable as integer no-undo.

/* do something to populate the variables...
 */

/* since you are apparently already saving changes to slinfo
 * you just need to add a few fields
 */

assign
  slinfo.name  = nameVariable
  slinfo.acode = acodeVariable
  slinfo.date  = today
  slinfo.seq   = seqVariable
.
```